# Can "mit" take the accusative?

Tags: preposition, declension

I came across these two phrases in my book:

> - mit dem Kopf nicken
> - mit den Kopf schütteln

Why is the second one in accusative?
Or is it just a mistake?

Comment: _"mit den Kopf schütteln"_ is a mistake. It doesn't make sense. But _"den Kopf schütteln"_ without _mit_ makes sense.

Comment: it was just a phrase, there was no sentence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I suspected, it is a mistake as "mit" always requires the dative case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78396/discussion-on-answer-by-evil-racehorse-mit-followed-by-accusative).